# Error on installing php-magicwand on RHEL (conflict between php-common)

Tags: imagemagick, php-7, rhel

I am trying to install ImageMagic (for php7) on RHEL7 hosted on AWS. 
After running

```
pecl install imagick
```

I end up with the following error

> configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program.

Thus I searched for `magickwand` which returned a possible match `php-magickwand.x86_64`.

Now comes the ultimate issue. When I try to install php-magickwand via yum, I receive the following error (check the 3rd last line).

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-magickwand.x86_64 0:1.0.9-6.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-magickwand-1.0.9-6.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-magickwand-1.0.9-6.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.2()(64bit) for package: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip.x86_64 0:0.10.1-8.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.19-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have searched for php-common-5.4 on my machine but there is nothing like it. All the packages I have is related to php7 (cause I never installed php55 on this machine).

Can someone please shed some light on where can I dig more? I at least Googled for an hour, no one seemed to fall into this trap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

`yum install ImageMagick-devel`

Comment: I did that mate. But weirdly this is what I get "No package ImageMagick-devel available"

Comment: Hmm... try this: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix

Comment: I already installed ImageMagick ( `Package ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version `), what I need is ImageMagick-devel